# extract list of subdirectories from input file

Tags: linux, scripting

I am new in scripting and need help on this one: I have a `.txt` file; in each line I have digits, for example:

```
123456
234567
345678
567890
....
```

On the other hand, in a master directory I have subdirectories. In each subdirectory, I have a file in `.xml` format. In each of the `.xml` files I have one tag with 6 digits; example: in file `1.xml` under sub directory `1`, the tag value is `123456`, in file `2.xml` under sub directory `2`, the tag value is `111111`, in file `3.xml` under sub directory `3`, the tag value is `345678`, ...

How can I extract the list of subdirectories and save to a file where there is a match in digits between `.txt` file and `.xml` files? Thanks

Comment: This is very unclear. You need to provide examples of ALL the input and the expected output, as well as what you've tried so far.  You are expected to try to solve the problem yourself first and show what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save in an output file lines in the xml file under sub directories having the string that I am searching for using the command line:

grep -r HDContent Priorite_2_HD/*/adi_new.xml

where Priorit_2_HD is the sub directory and adi_new.xml is the .xml file

The output looks like

Priorite_2_HD/ados_contre_attaquent_les_hd_vf_Ingest/adi_new.xml:                               
Priorite_2_HD/Ainsi_Soient_Ils_Saison_1_vf_W/adi_new.xml:                               
Priorite_2_HD/Ainsi_Soient_Ils_Serie_vf_W/adi_new.xml:                          
Priorite_2_HD/Amour_Haine_Propagande_Saison_1_vf_W/adi_new.xml:                         
Priorite_2_HD/Amour_Haine_Propagande_Saison_2_vf_W/adi_new.xml:                         
Priorite_2_HD/Amour_Haine_Propagande_Serie_vf_W/adi_new.xml:                            
Priorite_2_HD/Apparences_Saison_1_vf_W/adi_new.xml:                             
Priorite_2_HD/Apparences_Serie_vf_W/adi_new.xml:                                
Priorite_2_HD/Arthur_Saison_11_vf_W/adi_new.xml:

Now using awk i want to put in an output file all lines having the string HDContent="Y". trying to use the command line

awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } ; { if $3== "*Value="\Y\"*"; print $2, $3}' input.txt

but no luck . Thanks